# Planning to use angular 2, but our existing app is using angular 1.x. Is there any documentation on using angular 2 along with angular 1.x?

Tags: angularjs, angular

We will not be able to re write our app now also we don't want to create a new app for just angular 2. Trying to find a way to use both so that we can migrate slowly.

Answer (score 0):

on Angulars official site they have docs for converting form angular 1 to angular 2 located here [angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html) this will probably be your best bet rather than mixing angular one with angular 2.